# 'Vertical' logging with Nlog

Tags: logging, nlog

We currently use NLog as our logging framework, and it's working quite well. A feature that we'd like to add is the ability to force logging for a single object during runtime, so we'd be able to make calls like the one below.

```
_logger.Trace(IForceLog obj, string msg)
```

Where the interface is:

```
public interface IForceLog
{
   bool ForceLog { get; }
}
```

This would log if the logging level is at trace `||` obj.ForceLog.
Most of these calls would be from within the object, but some would be from others that deal with it.

The idea is that we have many objects of the same type, and sometimes we would like to see detailed logging for just one, and follow its behavior closely without clogging the logfile up.

Is there a standard way to go about this sort of thing?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this qualifies as an answer, but have you considered an approach where each object logs a unique id?  This way you could either use NLog's filtering capability to limit the amount of logging.  There is an old example here:  http://nlog-forum.1685105.n2.nabble.com/Config-examples-with-filters-td1685363.html

**BEGIN Copy from NLog forum:**

For completeness (and in case that link goes bad), here is the example inline:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<nlog>
    <targets>
        <target name="console" type="Console" layout="${logger} ${message}" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="console">
            <filters>
                <whenContains layout="${message}" substring="zzz" action="Ignore" />
            </filters>
        </logger>
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

This sample code:

```
using NLog; 
using NLog.Targets; 
using NLog.Targets.Wrappers; 

class Example 
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 
        Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Example"); 
        logger.Debug("log message"); 
        logger.Debug("log zzz message"); 
    } 
}
```

produces only "Example log message" (the second log message is filtered out by the

Alternatively you could use the new feature called Conditions (available in the latest snapshots) which let you write filters using a simple notation:

```
<filters>
    <when condition="contains(message,'zzz') 
              or level >= LogLevel.Warn 
              or level == LogLevel.Trace" action="Ingore" /> 
</filters>
```

**END Copy from NLog forum**

This does not directly answer your question (which I think is to execute certain logging statements, regardless of the configured log level and regardless of the logging method (Info, Debug, etc) used).  I suspect that it would be difficult to override/work around NLog's built in log level enabling.

If NLog's filtering does give you the desired results, how about logging to a database?  You could log everything, tagging certain objects' logging statements with a unique id.  Then you could use the database's filtering/grouping/sorting capability to view only those logging statements for certain objects.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

it's possible to use [EventContext-Layout-Renderer](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/EventContext-Layout-Renderer)

```
LogEventInfo theEvent = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Debug, "", obj.ToString());
  
IForceLog supportsIForceLog = obj as IForceLog;
If (supportsIForceLog!=null)
{
    theEvent.Properties["ForceLog"] = supportsIForceLog.ForceLog;
}

log.Log(theEvent);
```

and in your NLog.config file use
${event-context:item="ForceLog"}  in filter/when condition, as suggested in [wageoghe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125439/wageoghe)  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14405298/52277)